# achieving horizontal inline form for signup in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is the look I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Basically where it floats above a background image and is a form that submits a POST to another page.

Most importantly the first two text input fields blend into each other and the submit button is right on the left end.

How might I achieve this in bootstrap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just took the basic `form-inline` of bootstrap and gave the basic styles to look like your image. I do not know if that was just what you wanted, if you want something in particular, please specify it and I try to help you.

[**Check out this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/01fq0vnf/)

Comment: Works great! I'd suggest adding a `box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px gray;` to the `.form-inline` as that makes it stand out more

Comment: I'm glad to help and you are right in that way it looks even better