# bootstrap group inputs horizontally

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i have a multi line form and in one of the lines i want to group two input and a button horizontally using bootstrap. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3sv5hy2c/1/)

```
<form>
<div class="form-group">
    <lable>first :</lable>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="123" style="width:50px;"/> <span class="input-group-btn"
                                                                                        style="width:0px;"></span>

        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="test2" disabled/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <lable>second :</lable>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="123" style="width:50px;"/> <span class="input-group-btn"
                                                                                        style="width:0px;"></span>

        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="test2" disabled/> <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">...</button>
</span>

    </div>
</div>
```

the problem is white space between inputs :
[image]

how to align inputs and button side by side without space?

**Update :**
I don't want the second input that has value of 'test2' to be fixed width.but the first input and button with fixed width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this

```
<div class="form-wrapper">
    <form class="form-inline" role="form">
        <div class="form-group  fixed-width-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control fixed-width-input" id="ejemplo_email_2" placeholder="123">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group  fluid-width-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control fluid-width-input" id="ejemplo_password_2" placeholder="Test2">
        </div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn my-btn">...</button>
    </form>
</div>

.form-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
}
.form-inline {
    height: 34px;
}
.form-inline .form-control {
    width: 100%;
}
.form-inline .form-group {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    float: left;
}
.form-inline .fixed-width-group {
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;

.form-inline .fluid-width-group {
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
    border-radius: 0;
}
.form-inline .fixed-width-input {
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
 }
.form-inline .fluid-width-input {
    border-radius: 0;
}
.my-btn {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    background-color: #35bfd1;
    float: right;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    width: 100px;
}
.my-btn:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #31b0d5;
}
.fluid-width-input {
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

[**There is a jsfiddle example to play wiht**](http://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/93yosn40/).

Also look at this answer, maybe you find it is useful:

[**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854719/achieving-horizontal-inline-form-for-signup-in-bootstrap/30856980#30856980**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854719/achieving-horizontal-inline-form-for-signup-in-bootstrap/30856980#30856980)

Comment: tnx, but i don't want my form to be inline! i have multi line form .

Comment: @medusa, Why you say that the form is inline, you mean display: inline because it is not

Comment: i have multi form-group (two input and button together side by side )  in one complex form. i meant not in one line!

Comment: @medusa look at this http://jsfiddle.net/ma9g2oga/, is the same idea, I just add more form-group and I put in a wrapper(content-line), if this is not what you want please put a picture of exactly what you want and I will try to help you

Comment: exactly what i want! very tanx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can define the width on the other input and span that contains the button as seen below:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <lable>first :</lable>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="123" style="width:50px;" />
            <span class="input-group-btn" style="width:0px;"></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="test2" disabled/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <lable>second :</lable>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="123" style="width:50px;" />
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="test2" style="width:150px;" disabled /> 
            <span class="input-group-btn" style="width:50px;">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">...</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
<form>
```

**Update**:
Solutions that dont require fixed width

[input-group-field](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12732)

[Jsfiddle for input-group-field](http://jsfiddle.net/523Vc/1/)

Comment: I don't want the second input that has value of 'test2' to be fixed width.but the first input and button with fixed width.

Comment: okey, then maybe this can be something useful: Ref: [link](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12732)
JSFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/523Vc/1/)

Comment: tanx, i tried but i cant fix it for my code using input-group-field.

Answer (score 0):

just add this in your css file

```
.input-group-btn {
width:0;
```

}

this working [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kesavan49/avegs4gn/)

Comment: tanx, but it make the input with value 'test2' to be fixed width.